# Why copy the state before updating the datawindow?

Tags: powerbuilder

I just ran across the following code in a legacy Powerbuilder app, and I'm wondering if there's any real need for it, or if someone was in a belt-and-suspenders mood.

```
// Create a datastore that we can capture database errors in
lds_ds = create n_cst_base_datastore

// set up the datastore with the state of the datawindow
ll_Rc = adw_the_dw.GetFullState ( lblob )
ll_rc = lds_ds.SetFullState(lblob)

// set the transaction object
li_rc = lds_ds.SetTransObject(sqlca)

// call the update
li_Rc = lds_ds.update()

if li_rc = 1 then   // if successful then commit
    if ab_reset then
        adw_the_dw.ResetUpdate()
        COMMIT using sqlca;  // should check the commit return code
    end if
    li_return = 1
elseif li_rc = -1 then  // otherwise show error message
    if lds_ds.of_get_error() then
        lnv_error.of_process_sql_error( lds_ds.of_get_sql_code(), lds_ds.of_get_sql_errtext() )
    end if
    ROLLBACK;
    li_return = -1
else // better never happen
    ROLLBACK;
    li_return = -1
end if
```

It looks to me like you could get the same effect by just updating the DataWindow directly in this case, since we're not coordinating between multiple DWs

Answer (score 1):

One theory to explain it would be that the functionality of these two ancestor objects (the DataStore and the DataWindow) are somehow different. There's very obviously customization in n_cst_base_datastore or its ancestors (the of_ prefixed functions indicate that), but from this code it's impossible to tell about the ancestor of the DataWindow (or even if it has an ancestor).

There's also differences in functionality between DataWindows and DataStores, centered around the visual nature. For example, some DataWindow function failures will produce visual messages, while equivalent failures for a DataStore re will not. (SetFilter() comes to mind, but I can't confirm if that's an example right now.)

It's hard to tell the objective from the code snippet you've provided, but I can imagine some.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This section:

```
elseif li_rc = -1 then  // otherwise show error message
if lds_ds.of_get_error() then
    lnv_error.of_process_sql_error( lds_ds.of_get_sql_code(), lds_ds.of_get_sql_errtext() )
end if
ROLLBACK;
li_return = -1
```

may lead to locking problems depending upon when the error message is shown to the user.  If a messagebox is thrown up and the user has left for the day, you may be left with an open transaction.  Since the update has failed anyway, it is better to capture the error, rollback the transaction, then display the error to the user.

Comment: Good catch! Sadly, a lot of systems do that.